# jenkins - selecting downstream builds based on changes

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I have a github repo with multiple projects in it and a Jenkins job that runs our code quality, linting, etc. when a change is pushed there.  After that initial job, I want one or more downstream jobs to trigger based on which project/directory in the repo held the change.  Is there a plugin that makes this possible?

Comment: You shall be able to do it with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin

Comment: The plugin linked by @PiotrOktaba alone can't do this by  just configuring it. You have to write a few shell commands that access GitHub and return appropriate values for each repo to the _Conditional step_ configuration in Jenkins.